# How to solve error when opening SQL Server Data Tools from Visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

I installed Visual Studio 2010, visual studio SP1 , SQL server data tools (SSDT) 2012, and SQL server 2012 instance. But whenever i open SSIS packages (dtsx file) through Visual studio 2010 i get the below error. How do i resolve this ? Am i missing any installation or do i need to configure anything ? please help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2010

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843